# Flash Builder 4.6 - MultiDPIBitmapSource Issue

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Im new to flash builder, and have been searching for hours with no luck, can anyone explain why this is not working, when coded with the

Wont Work.

```
<s:BitmapImage id="pgImage" left="0" top="3"> 
    <s:source.normal>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="@Embed('assets160/{largeimage}')"
                                source240dpi="@Embed('assets240/{largeimage}')"
                                source320dpi="@Embed('assets320/{largeimage}')"/>
    </s:source.normal>
</s:BitmapImage>
```

Comment: what is not working? is it a runtime or compile error?

Comment: sorry post cut half my words.. yep no image appears, yet using no multidpisource and just the bitmapimage the {largeimage} pulls in my image

Comment: try to replace the {largeimage} by the name of the image... I did this test and it worked

Comment: yes in the part that was cut from my post. i mentioned it already works if i manaully add say. page1.jpg

Comment: it also works if i use say the normal basic way..<s:BitmapImage id="pgImage" left="0" top="10" source="assets320/{largeimage}" />

Comment: weird it doesn't work for me in the "normal basic way", we might have a different sdk version

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't embed an asset using a binding variable. The reason for this is that the compiler can not know what is in {largeimage} at compile time, since this information is only available at runtime.

So try removing the @Embed tag ...

Comment: thxs. but get the same result nothing appears..
     <s:BitmapImage left="0" top="3" id="pgImage">
      <s:source>
       <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="assets160/{largeimage}"
             source240dpi="assets240/{largeimage}"
             source320dpi="assets320/{largeimage}"/>
      </s:source>
     </s:BitmapImage>